# Not able to pass JWT authorization using Angular8

Tags: php, node.js, angular, typescript

Below php api script given by client when I run into local then Static data storing in api server successfully.

```
<?php
    //creating payload parameters:
    $classTitle = 'Demo Class on 3rd April, 2020';
    $classInfo = 'This is a demo class scheduled to understand API';
    $classDateTime = '2020-11-12 11:30 AM';
    $timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
    $classDuration = 15;
    $classRecording = 'yes';
    $classAutoStart = false;
    $recordingAutoStart = false;
    $classVideoRes = 720;


    /*xyz.com*/
    $apiKey = '12345';
    $secretKey = '12345';

    // Create token header as a JSON string
    $header = json_encode(['alg' => 'HS256','typ' => 'JWT']); // ensure to place first alg part and next typ part

    // Create token payload as a JSON string
    $payload = json_encode(['classTitle' => $classTitle ,'classInfo' => $classInfo ,'classDateTime' => $classDateTime ,'timezone' => $timezone ,'classDuration' => $classDuration ,'classRecording' => $classRecording ,'classAutoStart' => $classAutoStart ,'recordingAutoStart' => $recordingAutoStart ,'classVideoRes' => $classVideoRes ,'apiKey' => $apiKey]);

    // Encode Header to Base64Url String
    $base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));

    // Encode Payload to Base64Url String
    $base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($payload));

    // Create Signature Hash
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $secretKey , true);

    // Encode Signature to Base64Url String
    $base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));

    // creating JWT token variable
    $jwt_token = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;

    // creating authorization varibale
    $authorization = 'Bearer '.$jwt_token;

    ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax
        ({
        type: "POST",
         url: 'https://xyz/client/schedule',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "apiKey": "12345"
        }),
        dataType : 'json',
        headers: {
        'authorization': '<?php echo $authorization; ?>'
        },
        success: function(retval)
        {
        // alert(retval);
        console.log(retval);
        // var success = retval.success;
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Directly i pass parameters to above php api then also its not working, my senior told me you have to call above code from angular I wrote code but i am not able  to store successfully below is my angular code.

Below is my model class

```
export class Schedule1 {

classTitle: string;
classInfo: string;
classDateTime: string;
timezone: string;
classDuration: number;
classRecording:string;
classAutoStart: boolean;
recordingAutoStart: boolean;
classVideoRes: number;
    
   constructor() {
    
      
   }

  }
```

Below is component.ts on button click passing static values

```
import { Schedule1 } from '../Models/Schedule1.model'


   Schedule1: Schedule1 = new Schedule1();

    addSchedule(scheduleForm: NgForm): void {

    //static data parameter passing
    this.Schedule1.classTitle='hi Class on 3rd April, 2020';
    this.Schedule1.classInfo= 'This is a demo class scheduled to understand API';
    this.Schedule1.classDateTime= '2020-11-12 11:30 AM';
    this.Schedule1.timezone= 'Asia/Kolkata';
    this.Schedule1.classDuration= 15;
    this.Schedule1.classRecording= 'yes';
    this.Schedule1.classAutoStart= false;
    this.Schedule1.recordingAutoStart= false;
    this.Schedule1.classVideoRes= 720;


    //const data = JSON.stringify(this.Schedule1);
    const data = { 
    apiKey: "dcbf187d-bdfe-431b-8f60-fa19bf51cd85", 
    data:  JSON.stringify(this.Schedule1)
    } 

    this.subscription = this.userSvc
    .fetchData("https: //xyz.com/client/schedule", data)
    .subscribe(
    data => {
    // Data on Success
    console.log("data", data);
    },
    error => {
    console.log("error", error);
    }
    );

    }
```

Below is service.ts

```
  fetchData(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = {
    
    Authorization: "Bearer "+"1234",
     "My-Custom-Header": "foobar",
    contentType: "application/json"
    };

   return this.http.post(url, data, {
    headers
    });
   }
```

in console getting this error.

[image]

Comment: You are getting a 403 error and that means you are not passing the token correctly. The PHP code you have given above is for generating the token. You can use any of the libraries to generate token. Then your angular code should call this URL first and store the token in local session storage. You can use the token in all the consecutive calls.

Comment: check the request section in the network tab and see what sent to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try the following changes in your code to check if it works:

**First change:**

```
 const data = this.Schedule1;
```

**Second change**

```
 fetchData(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = {
    
    Authorization: "Bearer "+"dcbf187d-bdfe-431b-8f60-fa19bf51cd85",
     "My-Custom-Header": "foobar",
    contentType: "application/json"
    };

   return this.http.post(url, data, {
    headers
    });
   }
```

Comment: xyz.com/client/schedule:1 POST https ://xyz.com/client/schedule 502 (Bad Gateway)
Schedule:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https ://xyz.com/client/schedule' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
schedule.component.ts:145 error HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https: //xyz.com/client/schedule", ok: false, …} getting error in console log. @Prince

Comment: Please use this link to resolve the CORS issue - https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/#:~:text=CORS%20headers%20are%20simply%20HTTP,server%20at%20a%20different%20origin.

Comment: I added proxyconfig in option: 

"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my:build",
           "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my"
            }
          }
        }. @Prince

Comment: added new file in scr also: src/proxy.conf.json getting same error. @Prince

Comment: {
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://example.com/client/schedule",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}. @Prince

Comment: I am getting same error as you refer to above url. @Prince

Comment: Can you try adding below two lines at start of your php code: 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to define the type of request option that you passing to request so you have to use

```
return this.http.post(url, data, headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type':  'application/json',
   'My-Custom-Header': 'foobar',
   Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
}));`
```

also, you need to import HttpHeaders

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Try using unblock cors extension on your browser and check it again

Comment: After Prince answer getting error of xyz.com/client/schedule:1 POST https ://xyz.com/client/schedule 502 (Bad Gateway) Schedule:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https ://xyz.com/client/schedule' from origin 'localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. schedule.component.ts:145 error HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https: //xyz.com/client/schedule", ok: false, …} getting error in console log. @Mohammadamd

Comment: so you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` from the backend or your nginx @mohdmazharkhan

Comment: what is your backend language maybe I can help you with that or do you use Nginx? @mohdmazharkhan

Comment: In response i am getting this html: <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>. @Mohammadamd

Comment: Api developed by client i can not have permission from backend, i should pass directly from angular, from angular only i have to give setting some setting of cors, how shold i have to addd access-control-allow-headers in angular can you update your answer fully, @Mohammadamd

Comment: do you have access to the server?
please check /var/log/nginx/error.log for more detail about the error

Comment: you cant add this header in angular
actually, you need to add it from the backend side 
https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html
this should help you
@mohdmazharkhan

Comment: where i can get this location /var/log/nginx/error.log  from my angular files. @Mohammadamd

Comment: nop you need to get this location from your Nginx server

Comment: lets chat. @Mohammadamd

Comment: Nginx server means api server na. @Mohammadamd

Comment: Do you have whats app number. @Mohammadamd

Comment: It could be on the api server or it could be on another server

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error `'https ://xyz.com/client/schedule' from origin 'localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy` because server and client is running on different host, either you have to run server locally or try this,

open chrome using this command and check browser network tab

`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to setup a config file "src/proxy.conf.json"

```
{
    "/api/*": {
       "target": "http://localhost:4200",
       "secure": false,
       "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

and have your "angular.json" point to the config file

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
```

this will only be for testing purposes (since you have no access to the server, right ?)